Was bedeutet "doch noch"?
Könntet ihr mir bitte sagen, was doch noch im Satz unten bedeutet?

Wenn doch noch Mitarbeiter absagen, kann ich die Zimmer kostenfrei stornieren.

Ich habe die Wörter im Wörterbüchern nachgeschaut, aber ich kann nicht verstehen, was sie im Satz bedeuten.

Es gibt keinen Bedeutungswechsel durch die Kombination:

doch bedeutet entgegen dem vorher Gesagten, hier vielleicht der vorherigen Zusage, vgl. DWDS, Bedeutung 1, wodurch ein Gegensatz ausgedrückt wird
noch könnte hier auf Nachzügler hinweisen, d. h. dass die Frist für die Zusage vielleicht schon verstrichen ist, siehe DWDS; ich denke, hier passt Bedeutung 4.


Kurz gesagt: Man erwartet nicht mehr, dass noch Mitarbeiter absagen. Vielleicht ist eine Frist bereits abgelaufen, bis zu der sich die Mitarbeiter entscheiden mussten. Falls es aber trotzdem passiert und ein Mitarbeiter noch absagt, kann man die Zimmer stornieren.

Danke für die Erklärung. Jetzt verstehe ich. Es würde eine gute Antwort.

"Doch noch" hat (auch ohne vorherigen Satz) die compound-Bedeutung: "Im Falle (der unwahrscheinlich, nicht erwartet, hoffentlich nicht eintritt), dass..."

Nach meiner Meinung ist das Beispiel tatsächlich ein bisschen schwierig, aber es stimmt vermutlich, dass "doch noch" aus seinen einzelnen Bestandteilen verstanden werden kann. Trotzdem ist es eine feste Verbindung (mit nur einer Betonung).
Die Erläuterung für "doch" von guidot würde ich unterschreiben: Es signalisiert einen Gegensatz, entweder dazu, dass man es allgemein für unwahrscheinlich hält, oder es wurde vorher ausgeschlossen. Das "noch" ist aber schwierig, auch wenn man nur hätte: "Wenn noch Mitarbeiter absagen..."
Die allgemeine Bedeutung von "noch" ist, dass ein Sachverhalt, der vorher schon da war, sich in irgendeiner Weise erstmal fortsetzt (bevor es dann doch endet). Hier gibt es aber einige sehr weite Deutungen (Punkt 4 im DWDS finde ich in unserem Beispiel nicht so leicht wieder).
In einer Variante könnte es heißen "noch Mitarbeiter" = "noch mehr Mitarbeiter", d.h. es geht um weitere Mitarbeiter, zusätzlich zu denen, die schon angesprochen waren. In dieser Bedeutung müsste "noch" betont werden. Ich glaub nicht, dass das hier vorliegt.
Eine andere Variante ist: eine Situation, die das bisherige irgendwie um einen weiteren Schritt fortsetzt. Das kann dann sehr subtil werden. Ein Beispiel ist: "Ich dusche schnell noch, dann mach ich Essen". Dieses "noch" deutet an, dass es eine Reihe von Tätigkeiten gibt, und das Duschen ist der nächste Schritt dazu, bevor sich die Situation ändert. (Literatur dazu ist zitiert in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporaladverbial#Phasenadverbiale , diese subtileren Fälle sind dort aber nicht dargestellt). Hier angewandt, käme heraus: Die Absage der Mitarbeiter ist eine Fortsetzung der Situation, die wir bisher hatten. Das Bisherige könnten dann aber auch Zusagen sein!

"Wenn doch noch" means in this case: "falls" or "if / in case (of)" in english. But "in case of" would be more precise translated with "im Falle von". But it means the same thing.
